# getting error while running Map Reduce Program

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I am trying to run Map Reduce program and have also downloaded `commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar.` But I am still getting the following error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a MapReduce job run in a distributed way. That means that the job will run in a several computers that will require to have the library dependencies.

There are two ways: one is create a fat jar with all your libraries and the other is use HADOOP LIBS functionality to distribute your jar among the nodes.

https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/hadoop-add-third-party-libraries-to-mapreduce-job/